# Loading Mat-file into workspace using a function call

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of mat-files in my current folder which I wish to load to the workspace using a function. However when I call function they don't load into the workspace. Any idea why this may be and what could I do to load it to the workspace using a function?

For example if I have mat-files named `edemand.mat`, `weather.mat` by running an m-file loads them to my current workspace

```
% startscript.m
opc = 1;
global Twi NTUnew;
load('edemand');
load('tdemand');
load('weather');
```

```
>> run("startscript.m")
```

[image]

However adding the same code into a function and calling the function doesn't result in the values load into the workspace

```
%resetFunc.m
function resetFunc
    opc = 1;
    global Twi NTUnew;
    load('edemand');
    load('tdemand');
    load('weather');
end
```

```
>> clear
>> resetFunc
```

[image]

Comment: Inside the function you load the values in the function’s workspace, not the base workspace. This is by design and is a good thing. If you really want then in the base workspace, use a script not a function. Or write the function such that it return the data lodes. But you shouldn’t be working like that. Local data is better than global data.